# need help understanding for loop with mongodb aggregate $cond

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is intended (and successfully does) maintain the order of an array (var list) when using mongoDb's $in clause.

However, I'm not 100% clear on the logic of it.

I understand it's iterating backwards, to keep the order, but why would you assign ref to list at i -1 , and not i?

More of basic java script knowledge, but it's testing my current Noobness.

If someone could help me breakdown what's happening step-by-step, i'd appreciate it.

```
var list = [ 4, 2, 8 ];

var stack = [];

for (var i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

    var rec = {
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id", list[i-1] ] },
            i
        ]
    };

    if ( stack.length == 0 ) {
        rec["$cond"].push( i+1 );
    } else {
        var lval = stack.pop();
        rec["$cond"].push( lval );
    }

    stack.push( rec );

}

var pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": list } }},
    { "$project": { "weight": stack[0] }},
    { "$sort": { "weight": 1 } }
];

db.collection.aggregate( pipeline );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: `why would you assign ref to list at i -1 , and not i?`

Let's take the below example

```
var arr = [a,b,c,d,r,f];

console.log(arr.length); //This will give you 6
console.log(arr.indexOf('a'));// Will give you 0.
```

So if you want to access `f` from the array, you have to use

```
var index = arr[arr.length-1];
console.log(index); //This will give `f`;
```

Hope your doubt is clear now.

Test the code here:

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr.indexOf('a'));

var len = arr.length;
console.log(arr[len-1]);
console.log(arr[len]);
```